# SharePoint 2013 calculated column ( text + date )

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a column (created) witch the type is date ,and another column author witch the type is text , I wanna put the result of (author+created) in a calculated column ,I tried this and it doesn't work:
[author]&" "&TEXT([Created], "mmm-dd-yyyy"),I have this error :   Sorry ... We have encountered a problem The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported

can we put text + date  in a calculated column?
any solution?
can we do it with JavaScript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You formula seems to be correct. I did a test and it works on my dev machine. What can happen is that the formula for the date can be different due to your locale settings and language activation. The same goes for the name of the functions. For example: if my language is English, then TEXT-function will be recognized. But when for example Dutch is the language activated, i will have to use TEKST-function instead. 
Also the date format will be different so you might want to lookup the locale/datemask for your specific language.
Another important remarque is that in some language, the Excel-formulas (because that's what they are) sometimes take a , as delimiter and sometimes a ;.

So you might also want to play with this:

TEXT([Created]**,** "mmm-dd-yyyy")

TEXT([Created]**;** "mmm-dd-yyyy")

Another hint i can give you is just writing the formulas in Excel. If they work there, they should also work in SharePoint calculated column.

Comment: thanks you are right , it work now just fine , but my question is how to add managed properties from term store , in a calculated column ?

Comment: Not i think, as it is not a listed field in the calculated column settings. I think you will have to find your resort either in workflows or a farm solution using event receivers.

Comment: i'm using sharepoint online , so do you think we can develop it using javascript ?

Comment: farm solutions are not supported in sharepoint online i think, but using SharePoint designer you might be able to develop such sort of workflow. Allthough i don't use SP designer and workflows a lot, i cannot help you further unfortunately